# Using the hover tool with vbar glyphs

Tags: python, bokeh

### Question

Is it possible to use the hover tool with bokeh `vbar` glyphs?

### Problem

Using the same basic setup, I can get great tool tips with the hover tool on `circle` glyphs, but not `vbar` glyphs

### Demonstration

#### Setup

```
import numpy
import pandas
from bokeh import charts, plotting, models
plotting.output_notebook()

blue = 'STEELBLUE'
green = 'FORESTGREEN'

datalist = [
    {'month': 'Oct', 'rain': 131., 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 1},
    {'month': 'Nov', 'rain': 12.4, 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 2},
    {'month': 'Dec', 'rain': 43.0, 'snow': 13.5, 'wy_month': 3},
    {'month': 'Jan', 'rain': 63.0, 'snow':  9.2, 'wy_month': 4},
    {'month': 'Feb', 'rain': 72.6, 'snow': 35.3, 'wy_month': 5},
    {'month': 'Mar', 'rain': 13.5, 'snow':  4.2, 'wy_month': 6},
    {'month': 'Apr', 'rain': 107., 'snow':  1.5, 'wy_month': 7},
    {'month': 'May', 'rain': 77.0, 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 8},
    {'month': 'Jun', 'rain': 107., 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 9},
    {'month': 'Jul', 'rain': 216., 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 10},
    {'month': 'Aug', 'rain': 76.8, 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 11},
    {'month': 'Sep', 'rain': 76.4, 'snow':  0.0, 'wy_month': 12}
]

data = pandas.DataFrame(datalist).assign(total=lambda df: df['rain'] + df['snow'])
source = plotting.ColumnDataSource(data)

tooltips = [
    ("month", "@month"),
    ("rain", "@rain"),
    ("snow", "@snow"),
]
```

#### Successful with `circle` glyphs

```
hover_circle = models.HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips)
TOOLS_circle = [hover_circle, models.ResizeTool(), models.ResetTool()]

fig = plotting.figure(width=600, height=300, y_range=(0, 250),
                      x_range=data['month'].tolist(),
                      tools=TOOLS_circle)
fig.circle(x='wy_month', y='rain', color=blue, source=source)
fig.circle(x='wy_month', y='snow', color=green, source=source)
plotting.show(fig)
```

[image]

#### Unsuccessful with `vbar` glyphs

```
hover_bar = models.HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips)
TOOLS_bar = [hover_bar, models.ResizeTool(), models.ResetTool()]

fig = plotting.figure(width=600, height=300, y_range=(0, 250),
                      x_range=data['month'].tolist(),
                      tools=TOOLS_bar)
fig.vbar(x='wy_month', bottom=0, top='rain', width=0.5, color=blue, source=source)
fig.vbar(x='wy_month', bottom='rain', top='total', width=0.5, color=green, source=source)
plotting.show(fig)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This feature has been implemented and will be in `0.12.2`

Not yet, as of Bokeh `0.12.1`. Given the choice to add `vbar`/`hbar` without hit-testing support, or not add them at all, it was decided to be useful to the most number of users to make them available sooner rather than later. Adding hit-testing to these glyphs is a short term priority, though the team is stretched very thin at the moment. If you are interested in contributing, please reach out on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan. in the meantime I'll try to work around with some invisible `circle` glyphs below the bars.

Comment: Although the hover tool is working for `vbar` with the default mode (`mode='mouse'`), it does not work if `mode='vline'`. Bokeh 0.12.7.

Comment: @PJW please file a bug report on GH with a test case